# How to resolve HTTPS connection errors in mule?

Tags: https, mule, eloqua

Below is the end system(Eloqua) connection code.

```
 <http:request config-ref="Eloqua_Bulk_API" path="/customObjects/{customObjectId}/fields" method="GET" doc:name="Eloqua Get CDO fields">
                            <http:request-builder>
                                <http:uri-param paramName="customObjectId" value="#[flowVars.cdo.id]"/>
        </http:request-builder>
</http:request>
```

But not not getting proper repose, it is throwing below error message.

```
<CustomObjectFieldSearchResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
<ResponseStatus>
<ErrorCode>ArgumentNullException</ErrorCode>
<Message>As result 'CustomObjectFieldSearchResponse' is not a supported responseType, a defaultAction must be supplied
Parameter name: defaultAction</Message>
</ResponseStatus>
</CustomObjectFieldSearchResponse> 

Message               : Response code 500 mapped as failure.
Payload               : org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@1f0131c5
Element               : /SAPBWServiceReqInsertUpdate/input/0/0/EloquaLookupServiceRequestCDOBulk/subprocessors/1/EloquaLookupFields/subprocessors/0/0/1/2 @ nol-integration-nonmaven:bulk-integration.xml:92 (Eloqua Get CDO fields)
Element XML           : <http:request config-ref="Eloqua_Bulk_API" path="/customObjects/{customObjectId}/fields" method="GET" doc:name="Eloqua Get CDO fields">
                        <http:request-builder>
                        <http:uri-param paramName="customObjectId" value="#[flowVars.cdo.id]"></http:uri-param>
                        </http:request-builder>
                        </http:request>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 500 mapped as failure.
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.SuccessStatusCodeValidator.validate(SuccessStatusCodeValidator.java:37)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.validateResponse(DefaultHttpRequester.java:413)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:401)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:221)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.process(AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
```

when i try from SOAPUI it is fetching the data properly.

Comment: I think this has something to do with your SOAP/XML request payload that is being created before a call to web service is made.
You are able to hit the requested service,from the error message it seems its not getting required arguments in payload.
If it has been HTTPS issue,it could have thrown SSL/handshake exception.
Try to log the request payload and then compare it with the SOAP request you are making.

Comment: Hi, It same the request i'm making from soap and mule.

Answer (score 0):

I added added the below header in the request(http request/component). It is working fine.

name: Content-Type
value: application/json